# Custom format nav menu only using div and a

Tags: menus

I want to add a menu only using `<div>` and `<a>` to my Wordpress theme but I don't know how to do it.

When I put this code inside to head__menu class, it generate different menu with `<ul>` and `<li>`.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu')); ?>
```

Can anyone help me? My navbar code is on below

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" class="logo">
            </a>
            <label for="toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
            <div class="head__menu">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Tech</a>
                <a href="#">Game</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cool-line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a walker class that will do just that. Add this to your functions.php file;

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        !empty ( $class_names ) and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        $output .= "";
        $attributes  = '';
        !empty( $item->attr_title ) and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->target ) and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->xfn ) and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->url ) and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output = $args->before
        . "<a $attributes $class_names>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a>'
        . $args->link_after
        . $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}



function header_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => '',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',        
                'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => new Description_Walker
        )
    );
}
```

Then finally, in your theme header add a call to the nav header_nav() wherever you want your menu to appear. Here I have wrapped it with a NAV element;

```
  <nav class="" id="" role="navigation">
      <?php header_nav(); ?>
  </nav>
```

This should output this;

```
  <nav role="navigation" id="">
     <a class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item" href="#">Link 1</a>
     <a class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category" href="#">link 2</a>
     <a class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category" href="#">link 3</a>
  </nav>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159486/wordpress-change-header-navigation-list-items-to-div/12161295#12161295